# str_replace(&) outputs #038, how to avoid?

Tags: php

I try to replace & with string in my WordPress template:

```
str_replace("&", "et", get_the_title($id);
// outputs et#038;
```

I have avoided the problem by doing this:

```
str_replace("#038;", "et", str_replace("&", "", get_the_title($id)));
```

I'm pretty sure that this is not the proper way to solve the problem. What is the right way to replace & with php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$result = str_replace("&#038;", "et", get_the_title($id));
```

`&#038;` is the HTML entity for `&` used when displaing in HTML (or `&amp;`):

```
$result = str_replace("&", "et", html_entity_decode(get_the_title($id)));
```

But this would decode all entities which may not be good when displaying in a browser.

Comment: This is correct, it's a url encoded special character.

Comment: HTML entity actually.

Comment: Ya I saw you added that right after I did - great minds... :)

Comment: Me stupid, you smart. I thought I had tried the first option, but I had only "#038;", NOT "&#038;".

These both solutions work in my case, thank you.